# Non-iterable Object After \__init__ Array in Python Class

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, class

Say I would like to create a python class that behave as array of another class. While the __init__ is called, it recognizes itself as an array (iterable); however, when I call it again through some other method, or even call by the index, the object becomes non-iterable. I wonder which part I got it wrong, or perhaps, there's DO and DON'T for python class?

Last but not least, this is an attempt to simplify one object type to another (trying to cast from one class to another). Perhaps the code below will give a better clarification.

The example is below:
Say I have an object FOO

```py
FOO.name = "john"
FOO.records[0].a = 1
FOO.records[0].b = 2
FOO.records[1].a = 4
FOO.records[1].b = 5
```

And I create a python class

```py
class BAR:
    __init__(self, record):
        self.a = int(record.a)
        self.b = int(record.b)
```

and another class which would like to store BAR class as array

```py
class BARS:
    __init__(self,bars):
        self = numpy.array([]) # regardless the array type whether python native or Numpy it does not work
        for item in bars:
            self = numpy.append(self, BAR(item))
```

so what I would expect this code to perform would be that if I call

```py
A = BARS(FOO.records)
```

I would get an iterable A. But this does not work, though if I call SELF in BARS __init__, it would see SELF as iterable object.

If one should not expect python class to behave in this manner, at least I hope you could help pointing me out, what would be the alternative logical and pythonic way to achieve it.

Comment: The first thing is to drop numpy here. It gives you no benefits if you're trying to store custom objects. Use a list

Comment: Second, you can't just do an assignment to `self`. You'll need some attribute name. Beyond that, I'm not sure I properly follow what you're trying to do. You'll want `__iter__` to make a custom class iterable

Comment: For the list, and Numpy, I am well aware. for the `__iter__`, that's I have heard though never explore. Will have a look. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps answering my own question after a hint from comment above would be good.

It turns out that assining `self` in class as itself is a **DON'T** (silly me trying to get a shortcut).

To achieve an iterable class, one would require `__iter__` method alongside with `__next__`, and `__getitem__` to fulfill (maybe some others methods as well, but let's stick to these three for now).

So, the code above should look like this

```
class BARS:
    def __init__(self, records):
        self.records = [] # Use list for simplicity
        for record in records:
            self.records.append(BAR(record))

    def __iter__(self):
        self.n = 0
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.n < len(self.records):
            result = self.records[self.n]
            self.n += 1
            return result
        else:
            raise StopIteration

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.records[key]
```

Eventually, this will yield a iteration and index accessible object.

Comment: Nice turn-around. It's unusual for a new user to take feedback and actually research around it

Comment: Thanks to your feedbak ;)